# Count number of rows in window around timestamp

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table containing a time series in POSIXct format and some features (see example below). I want to add a column containing the number of rows within a window of `w` seconds around the timestamp.

So essentially what I need is this...

```
dt[, COUNT := 0]
for(i in seq(nrow(dt))) {
    interval_start <- dt[i,(TIMESTAMP - w)]
    interval_end <- dt[i,(TIMESTAMP + w)]
    dt[i, "COUNT"] <- nrow(dt[TIMESTAMP > interval_start & TIMESTAMP < interval_end])
}
```

... which is obviously very slow and usually not the way to do this. I played around a lot with `lapply()`, `.SD` , custom functions passed to `lapply()`, rolling joins but did not get it to work.

I did not think that something apparently easy would be my first post here.

```
              TIMESTAMP   FEAT1          FEAT2 COUNT (w = 2000 secs)
 1: 2017-11-16 02:50:19 2332843           1282     2
 2: 2017-11-16 03:01:38   40913            129     2
 3: 2017-11-16 08:07:03 2758077          15281     1
 4: 2017-11-16 09:33:31  156899            448     1
 5: 2017-11-16 11:00:04 3639410           1901     2
 6: 2017-11-16 11:01:50   46274            242     2
 7: 2017-11-16 12:00:46 3336248           1975     1
 8: 2017-11-16 16:31:16 3262457           1006     2
 9: 2017-11-16 16:37:33 3110064            840     2
10: 2017-11-16 17:23:06 3059651            765     3
11: 2017-11-16 17:31:57   51569            143     3
12: 2017-11-16 17:35:17 2254123            899     3
13: 2017-11-16 18:32:47 2321751           1182     3
14: 2017-11-16 19:02:11  469452           1257     3
15: 2017-11-16 19:02:23 2248207            923     3
16: 2017-11-16 19:40:25   62245            150     1
17: 2017-11-16 20:54:38 2245512            936     2
18: 2017-11-16 21:26:35 4191734           1044     3
19: 2017-11-16 21:30:08 2202018            958     2
20: 2017-11-16 23:42:37 2434562           2559     1
```

**UPDATE**
For now I'm using @Gautam's approach with some tweaks for more speed. Some experiments showed that this is much faster than the loop (20k rows: 35 vs 7 secs, 100k rows: 408 vs 175 secs).

```
tme <- dt$tme  
lower <- tme - w  
upper <- tme + w  
dt$count <- sapply(1:length(tme ), function(z) return(sum(tme > lower[z] & tme < upper[z])))
```

Still, if anybody knows the "data.table way" of doing this, I would love to know it.

Comment: Could you post the output of `dput(dt)` instead?

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out, I will remember this for future posts. And thank you @Gautam for doing this for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can also be solved using a *non-equi join* which seems also to be much faster (see benchmark below)

```
w <- 2000
DT[, COUNT := DT[.(lb = TIMESTAMP - w, ub = TIMESTAMP + w), 
                 on = .(TIMESTAMP > lb, TIMESTAMP < ub), by = .EACHI, .N]$N][]
```

> ```
>               TIMESTAMP   FEAT1 FEAT2 COUNT
>  1: 2017-11-16 02:50:19 2332843  1282     2
>  2: 2017-11-16 03:01:38   40913   129     2
>  3: 2017-11-16 08:07:03 2758077 15281     1
>  4: 2017-11-16 09:33:31  156899   448     1
>  5: 2017-11-16 11:00:04 3639410  1901     2
>  6: 2017-11-16 11:01:50   46274   242     2
>  7: 2017-11-16 12:00:46 3336248  1975     1
>  8: 2017-11-16 16:31:16 3262457  1006     2
>  9: 2017-11-16 16:37:33 3110064   840     2
> 10: 2017-11-16 17:23:06 3059651   765     3
> 11: 2017-11-16 17:31:57   51569   143     3
> 12: 2017-11-16 17:35:17 2254123   899     3
> 13: 2017-11-16 18:32:47 2321751  1182     3
> 14: 2017-11-16 19:02:11  469452  1257     3
> 15: 2017-11-16 19:02:23 2248207   923     3
> 16: 2017-11-16 19:40:25   62245   150     1
> 17: 2017-11-16 20:54:38 2245512   936     2
> 18: 2017-11-16 21:26:35 4191734  1044     3
> 19: 2017-11-16 21:30:08 2202018   958     2
> 20: 2017-11-16 23:42:37 2434562  2559     1
> ```

#### Data

```
DT <- readr::read_table(
"              TIMESTAMP   FEAT1          FEAT2 COUNT
 1: 2017-11-16 02:50:19 2332843           1282     2
 2: 2017-11-16 03:01:38   40913            129     2
 3: 2017-11-16 08:07:03 2758077          15281     1
 4: 2017-11-16 09:33:31  156899            448     1
 5: 2017-11-16 11:00:04 3639410           1901     2
 6: 2017-11-16 11:01:50   46274            242     2
 7: 2017-11-16 12:00:46 3336248           1975     1
 8: 2017-11-16 16:31:16 3262457           1006     2
 9: 2017-11-16 16:37:33 3110064            840     2
10: 2017-11-16 17:23:06 3059651            765     3
11: 2017-11-16 17:31:57   51569            143     3
12: 2017-11-16 17:35:17 2254123            899     3
13: 2017-11-16 18:32:47 2321751           1182     3
14: 2017-11-16 19:02:11  469452           1257     3
15: 2017-11-16 19:02:23 2248207            923     3
16: 2017-11-16 19:40:25   62245            150     1
17: 2017-11-16 20:54:38 2245512            936     2
18: 2017-11-16 21:26:35 4191734           1044     3
19: 2017-11-16 21:30:08 2202018            958     2
20: 2017-11-16 23:42:37 2434562           2559     1")
setDT(DT)[, c("X1", "COUNT") := NULL][]
```

#### Benchmark

```
# create data
w <- 2000
nr <- 2e3L
set.seed(123)
DT0 <- data.table(TIMESTAMP = sort(as.POSIXct("2017-11-16") + sample(w * nr, nr)),
                  FEAT1 = sample(1e6L, nr, TRUE),
                  FEAT2 = sample(1e4L, nr, TRUE))

library(microbenchmark)
bm <- microbenchmark(
  gautam = {
    dt <- copy(DT0)
    tme <- dt$TIMESTAMP  
    lower <- tme - w  
    upper <- tme + w  
    dt$count <- sapply(1:length(tme), function(z) return(sum(tme > lower[z] & tme < upper[z]))) 
  },
  cpak = {
    dt <- copy(DT0)
    dt$count <- apply(abs(outer(dt$TIMESTAMP, dt$TIMESTAMP, "-")), 2, function(i) sum(i < w))
  },
  nej = {
    DT <- copy(DT0)
    DT[, COUNT := DT[.(lb = TIMESTAMP - w, ub = TIMESTAMP + w), on = .(TIMESTAMP > lb, TIMESTAMP < ub), by = .EACHI, .N]$N][]
  },
  times = 11L
)

print(bm)
```

For 2 K rows, the timings for Gautam's and CPak's approaches are about 0.3 seconds which is in line with [OP's observations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48281856/count-number-of-rows-in-window-around-timestamp/48291795#comment83559154_48283774). However, the *non-equi join* is 75 times faster.

> ```
> Unit: milliseconds
>    expr        min         lq       mean     median        uq        max neval
>  gautam 269.222847 271.422632 278.196025 273.433669 284.92651 296.377010    11
>    cpak 269.657768 271.262771 294.905138 273.239062 275.24474 413.822440    11
>     nej   3.465766   3.539532   3.620397   3.589308   3.63731   3.901027    11
> ```

This speed advantages increases with problem size. If the number of rows is doubled to 4 K rows, the timings of CPak's approach "explode" to over 4 seconds. So, this method is excluded from further benchmarks.

> ```
> Unit: milliseconds
>    expr        min          lq        mean      median          uq        max neval
>  gautam  608.54028  616.835039  620.353603  625.129801  626.260266  627.39073     3
>    cpak 3901.07978 4044.341991 4168.566908 4187.604199 4302.310471 4417.01674     3
>     nej    5.43377    6.423977    8.372348    7.414183    9.841636   12.26909     3
> ```

For 10 K rows, the *non-equi join* is about 200 times faster than Gautam's approach:

> ```
> Unit: milliseconds
>    expr         min          lq        mean      median          uq         max neval
>  gautam 1914.750641 1921.824429 1947.393708 1928.414685 1945.286100 2048.810492    11
>     nej    9.142423    9.234898    9.382176    9.467979    9.507603    9.577044    11
> ```

If the number of rows is doubled (20 K rows), the processing time of Gautam's approach nearly triples to 5.4 sec which is in line with the timings reported by the OP. However, the *non-equi join* approach is now 300 times faster:

> ```
> Unit: milliseconds
>    expr       min         lq       mean     median        uq        max neval
>  gautam 5369.1104 5389.17756 5406.53040 5409.24468 5425.2404 5441.23607     3
>     nej   17.2523   17.25648   17.27597   17.26066   17.2878   17.31495     3
> ```

I didn't had the patience to test the 1 M row case.

Comment: So I just came back to this. This is in fact the "data.table way" I was looking for. Thank you very much. Is it possible to access the "TIMESTAMP" column via string (e.g. using with = FALSE or get())?

Comment: I am glad you are pleased. There are different ways, `get()` is one of them, `eval(parse())` is an alternative. The `on` parameter accepts a character string which can be created using `paste()` or `sprintf()`. There are some related Q on SO.

Answer (score 1):

Quick and dirty solution (not using `data.table`):

**DATA**

Figured I'd add data for others to try

```
> dput(d)
structure(list(tme = structure(c(1510800619, 1510801298, 1510819623, 
1510824811, 1510830004, 1510830110, 1510833646, 1510849876, 1510850253, 
1510852986, 1510853517, 1510853717, 1510857167, 1510858931, 1510858943, 
1510861225, 1510865678, 1510867595, 1510867808, 1510875757), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), feat1 = c(2332843L, 40913L, 2758077L, 
156899L, 3639410L, 46274L, 3336248L, 3262457L, 3110064L, 3059651L, 
51569L, 2254123L, 2321751L, 469452L, 2248207L, 62245L, 2245512L, 
4191734L, 2202018L, 2434562L), feat2 = c(1282L, 129L, 15281L, 
448L, 1901L, 242L, 1975L, 1006L, 840L, 765L, 143L, 899L, 1182L, 
1257L, 923L, 150L, 936L, 1044L, 958L, 2559L)), .Names = c("tme", 
"feat1", "feat2"), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-20L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000000000120788>)
```

**CODE**

```
d$count <- sapply(1:nrow(d), function(z) return(sum(d$tme %in% (d$tme[z]-2000):(d$tme[z]+2000))))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
> d
                    tme   feat1 feat2 count
 1: 2017-11-16 02:50:19 2332843  1282     2
 2: 2017-11-16 03:01:38   40913   129     2
 3: 2017-11-16 08:07:03 2758077 15281     1
 4: 2017-11-16 09:33:31  156899   448     1
 5: 2017-11-16 11:00:04 3639410  1901     2
 6: 2017-11-16 11:01:50   46274   242     2
 7: 2017-11-16 12:00:46 3336248  1975     1
 8: 2017-11-16 16:31:16 3262457  1006     2
 9: 2017-11-16 16:37:33 3110064   840     2
10: 2017-11-16 17:23:06 3059651   765     3
11: 2017-11-16 17:31:57   51569   143     3
12: 2017-11-16 17:35:17 2254123   899     3
13: 2017-11-16 18:32:47 2321751  1182     3
14: 2017-11-16 19:02:11  469452  1257     3
15: 2017-11-16 19:02:23 2248207   923     3
16: 2017-11-16 19:40:25   62245   150     1
17: 2017-11-16 20:54:38 2245512   936     2
18: 2017-11-16 21:26:35 4191734  1044     3
19: 2017-11-16 21:30:08 2202018   958     2
20: 2017-11-16 23:42:37 2434562  2559     1
```

I used `%in%` in the `sapply` call only as an example, you may want to use `<` and `>` instead which should take care of any time stamps where the seconds have a decimal point etc. The `2000` does not need to be hardcoded either.

I'm sure there's a more elegant way of doing this using `data.table`. Hope this is helpful!

Comment: Thank you, this does indeed speed up the process. I randomly samples 20k rows. This took my pc around 23 secs vs. 35 secs for the loop. I'm also pretty sure there is a more elegant data.table way of doing this, but for now I will use this.

Comment: Using `<` and `>` instead of `%in%` quite significantly sped it up further. Now I'm around 10 secs for 20k rows.

Comment: And I got it even faster:
`tme <- dt$tme  
lower <- tme - w  
upper <- tme + w  
dt$count <- sapply(1:length(tme ), function(z) return(sum(tme > lower[z] & tme < upper[z])))  `
This only takes around 7 seconds. I guess I'm fine with this. Thank you again.

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

Using @Gautam's data

I recommend using `outer`

```
window <- 2000
apply(abs(outer(dt$tme, dt$tme, "-")), 2, function(i) sum(i < window))
# 2 2 1 1 2 2 1 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 1 2 3 2 1
```

`outer(dt$tme, dt$tme, "-")` calculates time difference of every pairwise comparison - result is a matrix

`abs(...)` takes the absolute value of the time differences (of matrix)

`apply(..., 2, function(i) ...)` applies function to matrix column-wise

`function(i) sum(i < window)` - for each column returns sum of logical - is element < window?

Comment: The matrix is very RAM intensive for large data sets, why I can't use this on my pc (With 20k samples I get: Error: cannot allocate vector of size 3.0 Gb). But for the record, on a smaller data set (or with a bigger workstation), this is much faster than @Gautam's quick and dirty solution (on 2k rows 0.82 secs vs. 0.32 secs and 3.00 secs for the loop).